# Use same route for home page logged in and home page stranger

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

What would be the way to have the same home route: "/" for both home page logged in and home page stranger? E.g. after the login, the user is redirected to the "/" route with the logged in components data, and if the user logs out - he will be redirected to "/" as well, but with the home page stranger data inside.

I have 2 components: HomePageLoggedIn and HomePageStranger, and I'm trying to understand the way to display them under the same "/" route, based on a localStorage condition, prop, or other way.

I have tried to use localStorage to set a boolean for logged in, then to check in the App.js route declaration of "/" - whether the localStorage has true or false for the logged in value. It looks wrong to me:

```
<Route exact path="/">
     {localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn") &&
      localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn").length > 0 ? (
         <HomePageLoggedIn />
        ) : (
         <HomePageStranger />
      )}
</Route>
```

The problem is that the localStorage stores the flag slower than the redirect happens, thus the user lands on the home page stranger after logging in, and only after refreshing the page manually will he see the logged in page.

Comment: Where you are updating local storage value.  React listen only state and props value changes .Instead declare state variable and set it to local storage value  and update the state value with new value and local storage value also . U should use state value inside <Route>

Comment: you can use useEffect to get the local storage isLoggedIn value in some state and then you can use that state in ternary to perform the same.

Comment: If the rendered component from the Route is updated based on a state that reads the value from localStorage - I believe there's still a small chance for the user to land on the home page stranger after logging in.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to pass a prop from <Redirect... /> to the Router that decides what component to render: home page logged in or home page stranger. That way when the "/" route is called - it already knows what to display next.